# Is assigning service method result to component property at declaration time a good practice in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Inline property assignment or Lifecyle hook in angular components?

Is this a good practice assigning the result of a service method directly to a component property at declaration time, how could impact testability of that component?

```
export class MyComponent {
  dataValue: string = this.dataService.get();
  
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. There are lot of examples out there where you can see this pattern is  used. I don't see any issue with testability as such. I use it  too but usually with observables